# How to format money with cl-format (clojure implementation of common lisp format function)

Tags: clojure, common-lisp, string-formatting

I'm trying to use `cl-format` to format  money. I want `(f 12345.555) ;=> "12,345.56"`. I get the decimals with the format string `"~$"` and I get the comma separators with `"~:D"`. How do I combine them?

Comment: It's probably not a duplicate, but the answers to [In common lisp how can I format a floating point and specify grouping, group char and decimal separator char](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35012859/1281433) are probably relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the `~:d` directive only adds commas when passed a whole number (whether it's a float or an integer), i.e. if there's anything other than zero after the decimal point, `~:d` just prints out the number as is.    That's true for CL's `format` as well as for Clojure's `cl-format`.

A solution is to split up the number into an integer and a decimal, and then format them separately.  One way to do this would use a `truncate` function, which afaik, neither Clojure nor its standard libraries provides.  Here's one way, using `floor` and `ceil` from `clojure.math.numeric-tower`.  (Thanks to coredump for pointing out the bug in my earlier version.)

```
(defn truncate [x] 
  (if (neg? x)
    (ceil x)
    (floor x)))

(defn make-money [x]
  (let [int-part (truncate x)
        dec-part (- x int-part)]
    (cl-format nil "~:d~$" int-part dec-part)))

(make-money 123456789.123456789) ;=> "123,456,7890.12"
```

Note that this is only designed to work with positive numbers.
(EDIT: As Xavi pointed out in a comment, this isn't a solution, since there's a 4-digit group after the last comment.)

That answers OP's question (EDIT: Not really--see above), but I'll note that in Common Lisp, `~$` behaves slightly differently; by default it prints out an initial zero before the decimal point (at least in the implementations I tried--not sure if this is standardized).  This can be avoided by customizing the `~f` directive--which works this way in Clojure, too (see [Peter Seibel's introduction](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) for details):

```
(defun make-money (x)
  (let* ((int-part (truncate x))
         (dec-part (- x int-part)))
    (format nil "~:d~0,2f" int-part dec-part)))
```

You can get unexpected results with this definition if the numbers are too big.  I'm sure there are ways to avoid this problem by tweaking the definition, and in any event, as Joshua Taylor's comments point out, there are other, probably better ways to do this in Common Lisp.

Comment: What bothers me is "round", which rounds to the nearest integer (down or *up*). With an integer greater than the original number, you will have a negative decimal part and the whole printed string will be a mess.

Comment: @coredump  [truncate and ftruncate](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm) round toward zero.  That's the behavior you'd want, right?

Comment: @Mars ROUND (and TRUNCATE,  see previous comment)  return multiple values.  Instead of taking the difference,  you can do `(multiple-value-bind (quot rem) (truncate x) ...)`.

Comment: For even a bit more flexibility, see [In common lisp how can I format a floating point and specify grouping, group char and decimal separator char](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35012859/1281433).

Comment: Thanks @coredump for pointing out the mistake of using `round`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaTaylor for those comments.  I'd forgotten that these functions are multiple-value functions in CL.  Since OP was mainly asking about Clojure, I include the CL def only for comparison and clarification, and don't want to provide alternatives that would be very unlike the Clojure version.  However, I've added a reference to your comments so that people can follow up on other ways to do this in CL.

Comment: @Mars Thanks. Btw, I changed my answer thanks to your answer to avoid printing the leading zero.

Comment: That `make-money` function doesn't work. In the example's result ("123,456,7890.12") the group just before the decimal point has four digits!

Comment: Thanks @Xavi.  You're right!  I thought I'd try to fix it before replying, but it's not something I'm going to have time to look at in the next month, at least, so I'll just take my downvotes if they come.  I added warning, though.

Answer (score 6):

With Common Lisp, I would recommand using [`cl-l10n`](http://www.cliki.net/cl-l10n) which supports locales and defines `~N`. Alternatively, you could roll your own:

```
(defun money (stream number colonp atsignp &optional (decimal-places 2))
  (multiple-value-bind (integral decimal) (truncate number)
    (format stream
            (concatenate 'string
                         "~"
                         (and colonp ":")
                         (and atsignp "@")
                         "D"
                         "~0,vf")
            integral
            decimal-places
            (abs decimal))))

(setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)

(format nil "~2:@/money/" 123456789.123456789)
=> "+123,456,789.12"
```

Now, for Clojure, it seems that `~/` is not yet supported by `cl-format`, so you can't directly replicate the above code. It is probably quicker to use a Java libray (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format) or  [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)).

Comment: I figured it'd be a simple format string! Something like "~:D$" or whatever. I guess I'll just use that java answer you linked to. Thanks.

Comment: @madstap Format does so many things that we might forget it does not do everything ;-)